# How to install tcap/map protocol interfaces to linux?

Tags: dictionary, network-protocols, telecommunication

We want to find a software stack that supports map/tcap protocols. We do not want to use Dialogic. Is there any open source, free version for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Seagull" which is free and Open Source Multi-protocol traffic generator and it can be used to test TCAP protocol and others.